# properly update a link href after ajax request is sent

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a link in my rails app setup to make an ajax request

```
= link_to "link text", some_url, :remote => true
```

I also have a jquery click handler that will change the url when it is clicked

```
$('a').click(function() { 
  // change url to "other_url" 
});
```

The problem is that the link changes BEFORE my ajax request is sent. So the first time it's clicked, instead of going to "some_url" like it should, it ends up going to "other_url" instead.

Is there a simple/easy way to fix this? Currently I have an `ajax:complete` bound to the link so once the ajax response returns it will update the link. But this doesn't work for example if the user clicks on the link quickly a few times since the request isn't returned yet (thus link isn't updated yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `ajax:beforeSend` callback to disable clicking while the AJAX request is completing.  Then, change the URL to the new value in the `ajax:complete` callback.

In a click handler

```
$('a').click(function(){
  if($(this).attr("disabled") == "disabled"){
    return false;
  }
});
```

In the `ajax:beforeSend` callback something like....

```
$('a').removeAttr('data-remote');
$('a').attr("disabled","disabled");
```

And then in the `ajax:complete` callback something like

```
// Change the URL...
$('a').removeAttr('disabled');
$('a').attr('data-remote','true');
```

Comment: how do i disable a link that does an ajax request? `event.preventDefault()` doesn't seem to work